# HTML OnBeforeUnload function not working on browser close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onbeforeunload

In the body element I have  '**onBeforeUnload = "leaveChat()";**' with the purpose of eliminating the user ID from the database when he leaves the page (function code below). The function does its job when the user refreshes the page and when he goes to another URL. The problem is when the user closes the tab/browser directly, because his userID isn't deleted from the databases.

---

What do I have to add/remove from my code, so my script can eliminate the userID everytime, even when the users are closing the browser?

```
function leaveChat()
            {
            playTitleFlag = false;
            xmlHttp3 = GetXmlHttpObject();

            if (xmlHttp3 == null)
                {
                alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
                return;
                }

            var url = "leaveChat.php?userId=" + userId;
            xmlHttp3.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp3.onreadystatechange = stateChanged3;
            xmlHttp3.send(null);
            }

        function stateChanged3()
            {
            }
```

Comment: Can you include the way you attach `leaveChat` to `onBeforeUnload`?  What browser are you testing in?

Comment: You can execute synchronous code only in `onbeforeunload` handler. Asynchronous code allows the execution to leave the handler, and the default action will be executed, i.e. the page will be closed.

Comment: don't rely on browsers. Do it the other way round.  Send AJAX calls with 'I'm alive' signals, if signal is lost, take the user out of the database.

Comment: It's too late. What if user loses connection, or power? You need to rethink your process

Comment: Browsers will kill open HTTP requests, it is a race condition for the call to go out.

Comment: @xbakesx I test in Chrome atm. leaveChat is in the header in a bigger <script> where xmlHttp1, xmlHttp2, userId, etc are declared. The thing is that the script works in some scenarios and not when the tab closes, so I must find a solution exactly about the tab close problem.

Comment: There are 100's of posts here about exact same issue. Go through them and you will see the answers are all the same ... you can't do what you are trying to do

Comment: They are all right.  Unfortunately you have to basically have the client (this code) have a "keep alive" poll and then have something on the server clear out old sessions.

Comment: Ok then, thank you all for you input. I shall begin rethinking and rewriting then.